# Using MEAN to store data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I need help with a school project. Im making an app for creating and updating a list of issues that needs solving.

I have an input filed where im supposed to be insertingen the issue and then it should generate an ID, a status of "Open" and a datestamp.

Then the issue will show up in my output table. I have solved that i can display whats in the databas. Now i need to solve the part where im storing new data.

My plan is to use ng-click on my button AddIssue and call a function also named AddIssue. Then using $http post to send the data trough and then use moongose to store the data

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-controller="inputCtrl">
 <p>New issue <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="newIssue"></p>
 <button ng-click="AddIssue()"> Add </button>
 </div>

<div ng-controller="tableCtrl">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Issue</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="issue in issueList">
        <td>{{issue.status}}</td>
        <td>{{issue.issue}}</td>
        <td>{{issue.date}}</td>
        <td>{{issue.id}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**My JS file controller.js**

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 // Controller for input
 myApp.controller('inputCtrl', function($scope) {

// Call function when click on AddIssue btn
$scope.AddIssue = function() {

    console.log("Click click....")

    // Use Post to send data to database    
    $http.post('/issueList').sucess( function(response){
       $scope.newIssue = 'New issue';
    })


 }

}); // End of input
```

**server.js**

```
 /* Connect to db issues */
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/issues');

 var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

/* Connect to MongoDB */
db.once('open', function (callback) {
console.log("Connected to db");

// Created b-schema
issueSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: String,
    issue: String,
    date: String,
    status: String
});

// Create Model
Issue = mongoose.model('Issue', issueSchema );
```

This is so far that i have come, and now i need help with first how to send data from controller.js to server.js

And second using mongoose to store it on my mongodb issues

Comment: I think you should look at some examples to help you. That is a nice article about creating a todo app with the MEAN stack: https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route in your server.js for your POST and inside it you can save your issue object in mongodb.

Something like:

```
//addIssue
    app.post('/addIssue', function(request, response) {
        var issue = new Issue({
            id: request.body.id,
            issue: request.body.issue,
            date: request.body.date,
            status: request.body.status
        });

        return issue.save(function(err) {
           if(!err) {
               return response.send(issue);
           } else {
               console.log("ERROR adding issue:" + err);
           }
        });
    });
```

You need to install some npm packages too. For example:

> - body-parser (npm install body-parser)
> - express (npm install express)

etc.

Also you need to import them on your server.js file using:

```
var express =  require('express');
var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
```

This is just an example to clarify the idea. On a production environment the things are a little different.

Take a look at:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application

Comment: Thank you! I will try this solution and work with that idea

Comment: Do you know why im getting issueSchema is not a function?

Comment: It's "new Issue(..." and not "new issueSchema(...".

Comment: Yes i found the answer =) and now i have the object with me, but my next problem is that im getting Issue.save is not afunction

Comment: Paste the code on pastebin.com and send me the link if you wish.